# zend get youtube comments with query

Tags: zend-framework, youtube, comments, gdata

I want to get a video's comments in Zend by using a query, so that I can specify some extra parameters (max results, starting index etc) but I can't get it to work.

They way I fetch the comments is:

```
    $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
    $yt->getVideoCommentFeed($videoId);
```

I tried using an url as the second parameter, like so

```
    $url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $videoId . '/comments?max-results=5';
    $yt->getVideoCommentFeed($videoId,$url);
```

But it still doesn't work. And by not working I mean it returns the same results as before that it didn't have the url specified.

I tried to make a Zend_Gdata_Query but I'm not quite sure on how to build it. Any help? :)